# Load More Items at End of ListView in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to add more items to at the End of The listview when scrolling, and while doing my research I found this link https://montemagno.com/load-more-items-at-end-of-listview-in/, But when I tried to apply it on my code, I got stuck. I just want to know if someone can help with this. thank you in advance

Comment: "I got stuck" isn't a good description of the problem.  Are you getting errors or exceptions?  What is or isn't it doing that you expect?  What is the specific problem that you're having?

Comment: I don't what to replace Items with in my file

Comment: if you check the link, you will understand what I mean

Comment: Links can be provided for reference, but you must provide the appropriate context *in the question itself*. Links rot over time and can become useless, and so will the question if the relevant info isn't provided here. You should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) *in the body of the question* for it to be considered on-topic on Stack Overflow. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

In my precise I also tried to use this listview that James Montemagno made available, but I did not succeed as well.

I then left for another listview with infinite scroll and it's working for me to this day.

https://github.com/CarlosHSantos/XamarinMarvelApp

Comment: Could you please tell me under what file I can find it

Comment: This project I passed is another project different from James Montemagno, but can serve as an example of your problem, speaking of this, could be more specific about your problem, do you know exactly where the error may be?

Comment: if (e.Item.ToString() == Items[Items.Count - 1]) and                     Items.Add(string.Format("Item {0}", Items.Count));
 Basically Items should be replaced by something else, but I don't with what exactly

Comment: in the reference you passed, james declared the variable Items 'ObservableCollection <string> Items;' and 'Items = new ObservableCollection <string> ();' I can not see where you're stating it.

The mistake may be there.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be serveral Issues with your code:

1. You want your listViewJson.ItemsSource to be a ObservableCollection instead of a normal list. (I assume that it is a normal List, it is not obvious from the code your show)
2. You maybe want to implement the ItemAppearing in the following way:

   `ItemAppearing += async (sender, e) => 
        if (isLoading || jokeDisplay.value.Count == 0)
            return;
        //hit bottom!
        if (e.Item.ToString() == Items[Items.Count - 1])
        {
            await LoadItems();
       }
   };`
3. Lastly, within LoadItems() function, you need to replace Items with

   `(listViewJson.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<TypeOfTheItemHere>).Add(ItemToAddHere)`

It would be easier if you would have a property within your JokeList class that holds the ObservableCollection, so that you don't have to do all the casting everytime you want to access it.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work